# Store same instance of object in Dictionary & ObservableCollection

Tags: c#

I am building a WPF application. Lets say we have a supermaket; two types of objects called `Customer` and `Product`. A `Customer` object stores the `Product`s he has in his cart. I have two dictionaries where I am storing the instances of my `Customer` & `Product` objects (both are unique).

***Test Data***

*CustomerList* (`Dictionary<String,Customer>`)
| Customers|
| -------- |
| Customer A   |
| Customer B   |

*ProductList* (`Dictionary<String,Product>`)
| Products|
| -------- |
| Apple   |
| Banana   |
| Watermelon|
| Cucumber|

---

| CustomerA |
| --- |
| Apple |
| Banana |

| CustomerB |
| --- |
| Apple |
| Watermelon |

I have an `ObservableCollection` `CustomerList` of type `Customer` that I display and use to modify my `Customer`s (and their `Product`s). I want to implement the following: When I delete the product `Apple` from `ProductList` I want it to disappear from both `CustomerA`'s and `CustomerB`'s "cart". What I am thinking is that each `Customer` should store the products as pointers to required indices of `ProductList` (I have done some C++). However when I read online it seems pointers are a big no no in C#. Is there an easy to do this? I don't want to have to manage each `Customer` when I remove or modify a product from the `ProductList` making it "unavailable" for purchase.

Edit: added requirement that also I want to be able to modify Apple product in Productlist (for example renaming it to Red Apples) and have Customer A and Customer B “cart” also change accordingly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Items { get; set; }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    public Customer(string _name)
    {
        name = _name;
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    }

    public void AddItem(Product item)
    {
        Items.Add(item);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyRaised(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
}

public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private Guid guid;
    private double price;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    public Guid GUID
    {
        get
        {
            return guid;
        }
        set
        {
            guid = value;
        }
    }

    public double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
        set
        {
            price = value;
        }
    }

    public Product(string _name, double _price)
    {
        name = _name;
        price = _price;
        guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public void Modify(string _newname,double _price)
    {
        name = _newname;
        price = _price;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyRaised(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }

}

public class MarketServices
{
    // This will hold all my unique instances of Customer objects
    public Dictionary<String, Customer> CustomerObjectsMainList_Services = new Dictionary<String, Customer>();

    // This will hold all my unique instances of Product objects
    public Dictionary<String, Product> ProductObjectsMainList_Services = new Dictionary<String, Product>();

    // This will be used to display customers in a listview/datagrid and do modifications on it
    // I want the objects in this observable collection to be "linked" or "point" to the instances in CustomerObjectsMainList_Services
    // Such that if I modify any customername for example it would be reflected here too
    // Also changing any product name or removing any product from ProductObjectsMainList_Services should be reflect in the "cart" of all customers
    // in CustomerObjectsMainList_Services and CustomerObjectsList_Services
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerObjectsList_Services = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

    public MarketServices()
    {
        this.CreateCustomers();

        //Here I want to fill CustomerObjectsList_Services with the instances of customers in CustomerObjectsMainList_Services
        foreach (var kvp in CustomerObjectsMainList_Services)
            CustomerObjectsList_Services.Add(kvp.Value);

        //Now if I delete a product from the ProductObjectsMainList_Services, will it get reflected on the Customer objects?
    }

    public void CreateCustomers()
    {
        CustomerObjectsMainList_Services.Add("CustomerA", new Customer("CustomerA"));
        CustomerObjectsMainList_Services.Add("CustomerB", new Customer("CustomerB"));

        ProductObjectsMainList_Services.Add("Apple", new Product("Apple",10));
        ProductObjectsMainList_Services.Add("Banana", new Product("Banana",15));
        ProductObjectsMainList_Services.Add("Watermelon", new Product("Watermelon",20));
        ProductObjectsMainList_Services.Add("Cucumber", new Product("Cucumber",25));

        CustomerObjectsMainList_Services["CustomerA"].AddItem(ProductObjectsMainList_Services["Apple"]);
        CustomerObjectsMainList_Services["CustomerA"].AddItem(ProductObjectsMainList_Services["Banana"]);

        CustomerObjectsMainList_Services["CustomerB"].AddItem(ProductObjectsMainList_Services["Apple"]);
        CustomerObjectsMainList_Services["CustomerB"].AddItem(ProductObjectsMainList_Services["Watermelon"]);
    }
}


class Program
{
    public static void PrintCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        foreach (var x in customer.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}          {1}            {2}", x.Name, x.Price,x.GUID);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MarketServices test = new MarketServices();

        test.CustomerObjectsList_Services.Add(test.CustomerObjectsMainList_Services["CustomerA"]);
        test.CustomerObjectsList_Services.Add(test.CustomerObjectsMainList_Services["CustomerB"]);

        Console.WriteLine("Printing Customer A objects");
        PrintCustomer(test.CustomerObjectsMainList_Services["CustomerA"]);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Printing Customer B objects");
        PrintCustomer(test.CustomerObjectsMainList_Services["CustomerA"]);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        test.ProductObjectsMainList_Services["Apple"].Modify("Peaches",5);

        Console.WriteLine("Printing Customer A objects after changing Apples to Peaches");
        PrintCustomer(test.CustomerObjectsList_Services[0]);

        test.ProductObjectsMainList_Services["Peaches"] = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Printing Customer A objects after removing Peaches");

        PrintCustomer(test.CustomerObjectsList_Services[0]);

    }
}
```

}

Edit2: Modified code provided; the above works if I modify any product name or price. However I am not sure how to implement "Deleting" a product from ProductObjectsMainList_Services and having it removed from all customers that have this product in their "cart".

Comment: Well, one way to do this is to have a product be a singleton (one instance) with a bool flag such as "Available".  This won't remove the instance when you set it to true, but you could ignore (or remove) that product from any collection when checking the bool.

Comment: @zer0 will making it a singleton mean that I can only have one product object (Apple only?)

Comment: Singleton means one instance of a particular class.  So you could create say an Apple and Banana class.  And if products have shared properties, use an interface for both like `IProduct`.  So your dictionary, for example, would change to `Dictionary<String,IProduct>`.  You could also use an abstract base class here instead if all products share some code.

Comment: @zer0 thats not gunna work because my product list can be changed dynamically. I might add products during run time. Cant I do this with pointers like in C++?

Comment: You can create singletons at runtime pretty easily (I'd go with generics but not necessary).  Want an example?  Yes C# can use pointers, but now you're using `unsafe` code.

Comment: @zer0 can you share a simple example please.

Comment: @MElSawy - Can you please provide your class definitions ***and*** your sample data as valid C# code using those definitions? And code that populates the `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @Enigmativity just added code quickly. I dont have an IDE to test on my current laptop so I wrote it without one. I hope thats okay.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public double Price { get; init; }
    public bool Available { get; set; } = true;
}

//thread safe collection of single instances of products (by name)
//gurantees one instance of product class for a given name
public static class ProductList
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Product> allProducts 
    = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Product>();

    //creates product, or returns existing one if same one with name already exists
    public static Product AddProduct(string name, double price)
    {
        return allProducts.GetOrAdd(name, new Product { Name = name, Price = price });
    }

    //Gives you the only instance of that product
    public static Product GetProduct(string name) => allProducts[name];
}
```

Usage is simple.  Call `AddProduct` to create a new product.  Thread-safe and will never store a second instance in the dictionary of all products.

Then use `GetProduct` to get the only instance for that product name.

If you don't need thread safety you could use a `Dictionary` instead of `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Your edit makes this answer moot (which I can delete).  This presumes products are singletons based on name.

If you wanted to change the price, or anything but the unique key (name), you can simply modify the class instance.

Or change `AddProduct` to use `ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUdpate` to keep the same instance but modify it.

That said, this design goes out the window if you can't uniquely key on something (for the concurrent dictionary).

For example, renaming a product would be possible if there was a unique identifier (like product ID, etc...) that could be used for the dictionary key instead of name.

Comment: Thanks. This illustrates the singelton but how do I apply it for my case above? You mentioned adding a new product to the Product list; but how does the above solve my issue? (Remove or modifying apple product from productlist will remove or modify it from all customers)

Comment: thanks alot for your effort. I modified my post to add another issue (modifying or renaming the product). Have to sleep now, will try to understand and test your method in the morning. Thanks again.

Comment: @MElSawy Updated, but if there's no unique immutable key for an object, this approach is moot.  If there is some immutable key for a product, then I can answer your question about removal and things like that.  I suppose for a name change you could use the same instance, and change the dictionary key (remove old key, add new key, use same instance).  But then it's gonna get weird grabbing the product instance by a changing key...

Comment: Can you please take a look the code I provided. @Zer0. It works for modifying the name or product price. How do I implement "Deleting"? Aslso I think your code is missing some stuff (GetOrAdd method?)